# Edit betadisper permutest plot

Tags: r, label

[image]

I have used the script below to generate this betadisper plot between 2 communities.

In my "df", the first column is station names (x13)

I have 2 questions:

1. There is a point behind the "ABC" label, so how do I make the label transparent? Preferably adding different colours to each community?
2. How do I add the station names next to each point so I can visually compare which stations are most similar?

Script:

```
df <-read.csv("NMDS matrix_csv_NEW.csv", header=T, row.names=1, sep= ",")
df
Label<-rownames(df)
Label
dis <- vegdist(df)
groups <- factor(c(rep(1,8), rep(2,5)), labels = c("ABC","DEF")) 
groups
mod <- betadisper(dis, groups)
mod
anova(mod)
permutest(mod, pairwise = TRUE)
plot(mod)
plot(mod, ellipse = TRUE, hull = FALSE, main= "MultiVariate Permutation")
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer 2), here's how to plot the station names on top of the points.

```
text(mod$vectors[,1:2], label=Label)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibile solution to your problem.
Download the `myplotbetadisp.r` file from this [link](https://pastebin.com/qhjvZmhB) and place the file in the working directory (warning, do not save the file as `myplotbetadisp.r.txt`!).
Some additional options are available in `myplotbetadisper` function:
`fillrect`, filling color of the box where centroid labels are printed;
`coltextrect`, vector of colors for centroid labels;
`alphaPoints`, alpha trasparency for centroid points;
`labpoints`,  vectors of labels plotted close to points;
`poslabPoints`, position specifier for the text in `labpoints`.

```
library(vegan)
# A dummy data generation process
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
df <- matrix(runif(13*n),nrow=13)

# Compute dissimilarity indices
dis <- vegdist(df)
groups <- factor(c(rep(1,8), rep(2,5)), labels = c("ABC","DEF")) 

# Analysis of multivariate homogeneity of group dispersions
mod <- betadisper(dis, groups)

source("myplotbetadisp.r")
labPts <- LETTERS[1:13]
col.fill.rect <- addAlpha(col2rgb("gray65"), alpha=0.5)
col.text.rect <- apply(col2rgb(c("blue","darkgreen")), 2, addAlpha, alpha=0.5)
transp.centroids <- 0.7

myplotbetadisper(mod, ellipse = TRUE, hull = FALSE, 
    fillrect=col.fill.rect, coltextrect=col.text.rect, 
    alphaPoints=transp.centroids, labPoints=labPts,
    main= "MultiVariate Permutation")
```

Here is the plot

[image]

Hope it can help you.